# Can one represent a generalized hypergeometric function 1F2 as a product of two confluent hypergeometric functions?

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions, real-analysis

I am trying to somewhat simplify a series, whose coefficients feature generalised hypergeometric functions ${}_1F_2(1;a,a+1;z)$. I was unable to find useful functional relations for this specific combination of parameters (I tried the new NIST Handbook, third volume of A.P. Prudnikov, Brychkov & Marychev's "Integrals and Series" and all online sources I could get my hands on).

Interestingly, L.J. Slater mentions on p.47 of her book "Generalized Hypergeometric Functions" that

${}_1F_2(a;b,c;z)$ *is the product of two confluent hypergeometric functions*

and gives a reference to the paper of F.J.W. Whipple (1927) in *J. Lond. Math. Soc.*, 2, p. 85, which is focussed on relationships between functions ${}_3F_2$ and ${}_4F_3$. I must be missing something here, but I cannot figure out how Whipple's paper supports the Slater's statement. Therefore, my question is

1. Is it really possible to represent generalized hypergeometric functions ${}_1F_2(a;b,c;z)$ with arbitrary (within reason) parameters $a$, $b$ and $c$ as a product of two confluent hypergeometric functions?
2. If yes, could you please point me in a direction of the relevant book/paper/formula/derivation?

Comment: This is a proper link to the mentioned paper: [F.J.W. Whipple (1927) "", *J. Lond. Math. Soc.,* **2**(2), pp. 85-90](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-2.2.85).

Comment: Maple expresses your function in terms of a Lommel S1 function:
$${\mbox{$_1$F$_2$}(1;\,a,a+1;\,z)}=4\,{\frac {{\it LommelS1} \left( -2+
2\,a,1,2\,\sqrt {-z} \right)  \left( a-1 \right) a}{ \left( 2\,\sqrt {
-z} \right) ^{2\,a-1}}}
$$

Comment: @Robert Israel: This is very interesting. Could you please explain how you obtained this identity? I use Maple 13 and have not been able to obtain something this compact directly.

Comment: Just found a formula underlying Robert Israel's result in Watson's "Treatise on the Theory of Bessel functions" (1966), Section 10.7, Equation (10):
\begin{align}
& s_{\mu,\nu}(z)=\frac{z^{\mu+1}}{(\mu-\nu+1)(\mu+\nu+1)} \\
&\qquad\qquad \times{}_1F_2\left( {\textstyle 1;\frac{1}{2}\mu-\frac{1}{2}\nu+\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\mu+\frac{1}{2}\nu+\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{4}z^2} \right)\,.
\end{align}

Comment: In Maple 16: 

> FunctionAdvisor(specialize, hypergeom([1],[a,a+1],z));

Comment: @Robert Israel: Thanks you very much. This also works in Maple 13.

Comment: I did not find anything about $_{1}F_{2}$ in the cited paper of Whipple. It seems there are no such factorization via more simple hypergeometric functions at least for general parameters. Otherwise a problem of asymptotics of $_{1}F_{2}$ zeroes would be reduced somehow to something reasonable. But this is unsolved problem as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the relevant paper is in fact [C. T. Preece (1923) in Proceedings of The London Mathematical Society, Volume s2-22, Issue 1, p. 370](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/plms/s2-22.1.370/pdf). Identities such as

$
\left\{ {}_1\mathcal{F}_1\left(a;2a;x\right)\right\}^2 = e^x {}_1\mathcal{F}_2(a;2a,a+1/2;x^2/4)
$

are provided. There don't seem to be any with more than one free parameter, however.